# Why this query does't use index-only scan in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with 28 columns and 7M records without primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE records (
  direction smallint,
  exporters_id integer,
  time_stamp integer
  ...
)
```

I create index on this table and vacuum table after that (autovacuum is on)

```
CREATE INDEX exporter_dir_time_only_index ON sacopre_records
USING btree (exporters_id, direction, time_stamp);
```

and i want execute this query

```
SELECT count(exporters_id) FROM records WHERE exporters_id = 50
```

The table has 6982224 records with exporters_id = 50. I expected this query use index-only scan to get results but it used sequential scan.
This is "EXPLAIN ANALYZE" output:

```
Aggregate  (cost=204562.25..204562.26 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1521.862..1521.862 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Seq Scan on sacopre_records (cost=0.00..187106.88 rows=6982149 width=4) (actual time=0.885..1216.211 rows=6982224 loops=1)
    Filter: (exporters_id = 50)
    Rows Removed by Filter: 2663
Total runtime: 1521.886 ms
```

but when I change the exporters_id to another id, query use index-only scan

```
Aggregate  (cost=46.05..46.06 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.321..0.321 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Index Only Scan using exporter_dir_time_only_index on sacopre_records  (cost=0.43..42.85 rows=1281 width=4) (actual time=0.313..0.315 rows=4 loops=1)
    Index Cond: (exporters_id = 47)
    Heap Fetches: 0
Total runtime: 0.358 ms
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT COUNT(exporters_id=50) FROM records`?

Comment: @Tordek, I test it now and get same result, it use seq-scan.

Comment: maybe new index is not analyzed and therefore presented to planner?.. try `vacuum analyze records`

Comment: @VaoTsun, I said that above , I executed "vacuum analyze" and auto vacuum is on.

Answer (score 5):

The explain is telling you the reason. Look closer.

```
Aggregate  (cost=204562.25..204562.26 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=1521.862..1521.862 rows=1 loops=1)
->  Seq Scan on sacopre_records (cost=0.00..187106.88 rows=6982149 width=4) (actual time=0.885..1216.211 rows=6982224 loops=1)
    Filter: (exporters_id = 50)
    Rows Removed by Filter: 2663
Total runtime: 1521.886 ms
```

Your filter is removing only 2663 rows out of the total amount of 6982149 rows in the table, hence doing a sequential scan should really be faster than using an index, as the disk head should pass through 6982149 - 2663 = 6979486 records anyway. The disk head is starting to read the entire table sequentially and on the way is removing that tiny fraction (0.000004 %) that does not match your criteria. While in the index scan case it should jump from the index file(s) and get back to the data file(s) 6979486 times, which for sure should be slower than these 1.5 seconds you are getting now!

Comment: "and back to the data file"... but they're doing a `COUNT`, over an indexed field, surely the engine could just traverse the index and ignore the data?

Comment: i agree with @Tordek, that is not necessary to back to the data file!!

Comment: Select result is {50}.  Index type is btree, so I think getting result from index can be faster  than searching data file.

Comment: Indeed, 50 **is** the most common value and therefore it is not used by the index for a very good reason. You can try `SET enable_seqscan = OFF;` and then run the same `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to see whether the planner is right or not.

Comment: @KouberSaparev Re most common values: that's wrong. That might be the case in some DBMSes, but in PostgreSQL a b-tree index *does* contain all the values, common or otherwise, unless you make it a partial index with an explicit `WHERE` clause in the index definition. It is useful for it to do so, too, for things like index-only scans, or for returning index-ordered results efficiently. Your second point, though, is correct: most likely the index isn't used here because it's not selective enough, and testing with `enable_seqscan = off` is useful to see the relative cost estimates.

Comment: when I set `enable_seqscan = off` my query take 0.760s on index only scan, but when I enable seqscan it takes 1.304s on seq-scan with same result.

Comment: @CraigRinger and @KouberSaparev , the cost is `0.00..187066.89` on seq-scan and it's `0.43..229752.80` on index-only

Comment: @Arshen Most likely your `random_page_cost` and `seq_page_cost` don't accurately reflect your system's actual performance then. Or the planner isn't estimating very well. That's not a huge difference, though.

Comment: @CraigRinger, in fact you are right, the `most_common_vals` are contained within the index, my bad.